# Contour Integral involving Dilogarithmic functions

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration, polylogarithm

I am considering the contour integral: 
$\int Li_2\left( \frac{1-z}{2}\right)Li_2\left( \frac{z-1}{2z}\right) \frac{dz}{z}$.

The contour of integration is the unit circle excluding the pole $z = 0$. $Li_2(z)$ is the dilogarithm function also known as Spence function. We thus have four parts to evaluate in this integration:

a - The unit circle in which we set $z = e^{it}$, $0<t<2 \pi$

b - The real negatively oriented segment, set $z = x$, $x$ runs from $1$ to $0$

c - The small limit integral , set $z = \epsilon e^{it}$, $t$ goes from $2 \pi$ to $0$.

d - The real positively oriented segment, set $z = x$, $x$ runs from $0$ to $1$

It is obvious integrals in (b) and (d) cancel each other, and (a) is easy to set and it is finite. However, I am having a problem in solving integral (c), when you set $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the integral diverges having the term $\ln^2(\epsilon)$. I am using the relation $Li_2(z) + Li_2(\frac{1}{z}) = -\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{2} \ln^2(-z)$ for small $z$

Applying Cauchy Integral theorem, this contour integral should be zero because the function is analytic everywhere in the open unit disk except at $z = 0$ and we are excluding this point in our contour. Thus $I_a = -I_c$.

Any hint on how to evaluate $I_c$?

Thank you for your valuable support

Comment: I don't understand what is your contour. $\text{Li}_2(\frac{1-1/z}{2})$ isn't meromorphic on $|z| \le 1$, it has a branch point at $z=0$. But $\text{Li}_2(\frac{1-z}{2})(\text{Li}_2(\frac{2z}{z-1})-\frac{\pi^2}{6})$ is analytic for $|z|\le r$ small enough.

Comment: Hi, My contour is visualized on this site: https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/FrancescoHautmann/ComplexVariable/s1_12_sl9.pdf

Comment: I am using a branch cut from 0 to 1 in order to exclude the singularity z = 0. The function becomes analytic inside this contour. I did not understand why you subtracted $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ from the second term of the function.

Comment: In that case $\int_C f(z)dz = 0$ as $f$ is analytic inside $C$. Next time copy and paste the contour as an image

Comment: I definitely know it is 0 by Cauchy integral theorem. My problem is that $I_a$ is finite while $I_c$ is infinite. thus their sum cannot be zero!!

Comment: If I am correct that $I_b + I_d = 0$, we thus must have $I_a + I_c = 0$. 44

Comment: Ignore the 0.44 in the last comment, $I_a + I_c = 0$. however in the limiting case as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$, $I_c$ is diverging. I am sure $I_a$ is finite, I have evaluated numerically. I am speculating a bout a bug somewhere in the analysis.

Comment: Then $I_c$ isn't infinite. Or maybe I'm wrong it is analytic inside $C$, it is hard to visualize $\text{Li}_2(z)$ outside $|z| < 1$. Also it should not be true $I_b,I_d$ cancel (due to the branches)

Comment: How to show that $I_b$ and $I_d$ do not cancel?

Comment: Why is it hard to visualize $Li_2(z)$ outside the unit disk. Check the functional relation in my question. Aside, you do not need to visualize it outside the unit disk.